# Swagger-UI : Need Help on swagger to customize the input payload

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

As per the issue below on GIT, there is provision to provide the input text box for request body but I am not able to find the details how we can use this feature using .net core web API. Can somebody guide me on this will be really appreciated?
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/1589

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far and explain how is it not working?

Comment: @Helen: I am new to the Swagger, I am currently having a request JSON body where I want instead of key-value pair key and text-box/dropdown should be used. Could you guide me step by step or give any link which could be useful?